# add dynamic field to serializer class

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

In my serializer class, I have defined two properties, and the third property could be derived from those two properties. Please see the code below

```
class ItemNameSerializer(NestedCreateUpdateMixin, ModelSerializer):
    nested_child_field_name = 'attribute_names'
    nested_child_serializer = AttributeNameSerializer

    attribute_names = AttributeNameSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ItemName
        fields = '__all__'
```

From the above code, we can see that

`attribute_names = AttributeNameSerializer(many=True)`

can be derived by

`[nested_child_field_name] = nested_child_serializer(many=true)`

So my question is

1. **can I add a dynamic field which will be derived from other fields (to avoid writing redundant code) ?**
2. **if yes then how ?**

the possible solutions can be of two types

A. overriding some `ModelSerializer` method.

B. generalized solution for any python class.

please try to provide both type of solutions (if possible)(and may be of some another type ?)

Comment: Wouldn't be these two fields duplicate of one another? Why would you need such a thing?

Comment: @AmirAfianian I need "attribute_names = AttributeNameSerializer(many=True)" for sending result and 'nested_child_field_name' & 'nested_child_serializer' for 'NestedCreateUpdateMixin'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found the Answer myself.

**The `serializer` specific answer:**

*Turns out django rest frame work initialise the fields from `deepcopy` of instance (irrelevant)*

But you can override `__init__` method of the serializer and add field in `self.fields`. In my case I did it in the `NestedCreateUpdateMixin` where `nested_child_field_name` and `nested_child_serializer` already available

please see following code

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NestedCreateUpdateMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields[self.nested_child_field_name] = self.nested_child_serializer(many=True)
```